# Admins that only control a subset of users

Tags: users

I am creating a page where users pay to create and edit their custom content.

These clients need to use multiple accounts with certain edit-rights - so they need their own people-management.

These are my requirements in that respect:

- Each client-admin belongs to an organization that can have multiple members
- Each organizatin "owns" certain content
- Each client-user can edit content of his organization but only if the client-admin has granted him these rights

Is there a way that I can create admins that only control a subset of users?

(I found the https://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole module, but with that I would need a new role for each client. Is that a good solution? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [Organic Groups](https://drupal.org/project/og).

> [Organic Groups] Enable users to create and manage their own 'groups'. Each group can have subscribers, and maintains a group home page where subscribers communicate amongst themselves.
>
> They do so by posting the usual node types: blog, story, page, etc. A block is shown on the group home page which facilitates these posts. The block also provides summary information about the group.
>
> Groups may be selective or not. Selective groups require approval in order to become a member, or even invitation -only groups. There are lots of preferences to configure groups as you need.

It is a fairly complex module, but I think it is very well suited for your use-case.

Comment: It seems to be working quite well! I haven't figured out how to assign a member to only certain nodes of the group (as opposed to certain content-types) but it's almost there! (And if that doesn't work, we can still just drop that use-case.)